# How to get nightwatch to output to include console.log commands from the browser app

Tags: travis-ci, nightwatch.js, console.log

Is there any way to log to the nightwatch output console when running console.log in the browser app? This would be useful in CI where its hard to debug issues?

Answer (score 2):

There is no event from the browser that tells the framework when there is a console message but you can get the browser console with `.getLog`.

Now you still have to figure out when to call it. Personally I use it when I'm switching to a new page.

```
browser.getLog('browser', function(logEntriesArray) {
  if (logEntriesArray.length) {
    console.log('Log length: ' + logEntriesArray.length);
    logEntriesArray.forEach(function(log) {
      console.log(
        '[' + log.level + '] ' + log.timestamp + ' : ' + log.message
      );
    });
  }
});
```